# Error with class containing an array of another class object

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

Can someone please tell me what the fudge I am doing wrong?  In c I can define a struct to do this in c# I have been banging my head on a wall for an entire day and cannot figure out this code does not work????   I am trying to define a class / struct (SData) that have two string elements color and value.  Then I define a class / struct (DataPacket) that has an array of 13 of the SData objects.  I instantiate a DataPacket object dp and try to assign a string to dp.sd[0].color and it throws a null ref exception.  The value of `dp.sd[]` in VS locval variables is `SData[13]` and every element is a `ObjArrayProb.SData = null`????

The local variable viewer does not show sd[].color and sd[].value it just shows a single pointer for every ObjArrayProb.SData[] element pointing to null??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ObjArrayProb
{
    class SData
    {
        public string color;
        public string value;
    }

    class DataPacket
    {
        public string soh;
        public string sid;
        public SData[] sd;
        public string sm;
        public string eot;

        public DataPacket()
        {
            sd = new SData[13]; <---- this should instantiate 13 SData objects
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataPacket dp = new DataPacket();

            dp.sd[0].color = "1"; <--  this line throws a nullreferenceException and dp.sd[0] -> null and not a SData object???

            Console.WriteLine("sd[0].color = " + dp.sd[0].color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to instantiating the `sd` array, you also need to instantiate *every object in that array*.

Comment: You *just* defined the array of 13 elements, all the elements are still not initialized. You need `dp.sd[0] = new SData();` and later you can access the `color` property. Also, they are classes, not `struct`.

Comment: As a side not see [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: If it has been asked before and answered please link the answer as I could not find an answer.  I don't understand why I need to do dp.sd[0] = new SData()?  What did sd = new SData[13] do in the DataPacket constructor do?  I thought it creates 13 SData objects?

Comment: dp.sd[0] = new SData(); did the trick.  I am still a bit confused though as I don't quite understand what the line sd = new Sdata[13] did in the constructor.  I thought that would instantiate 13 Sdata objects???

Comment: @ctBram - If your class (SData) had been a struct then you would have 13 instances of the struct without having to use **new** to create the individual objects.  But since it is a class, your line of code only created an array with 13 references to the class (SData), but they were all null references.  So you need to instantiate each one using **new**.